# datatrigger on enum to change image

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a button with a fixed background image and would like to show a small overlay image on top of it. Which overlay image to chose depends on a dependency property (`LapCounterPingStatus`) of the according viewmodel.

This is what I got so far:

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
        <Image Stretch="None"> <!-- Background Image -->
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/Pingn.png"/>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
        <Image Stretch="None" Panel.ZIndex="1"> <!-- Small Overlay Image -->
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LapCounterPingStatus}" Value="PingStatus.PING_UNKNOWN">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/RefreshOverlayn.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LapCounterPingStatus}" Value="PingStatus.PING_FAILURE">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/ErrorOverlayn.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LapCounterPingStatus}" Value="PingStatus.PING_SUCCESS">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/CheckmarkOverlayn.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Relevant parts of my viewmodel

```
public class ConfigurationViewModel
{
    public enum PingStatus { PING_UNKNOWN, PING_SUCCESS, PING_FAILURE };

    public PingStatus LapCounterPingStatus
    {
        get { return _lapCounterPingStatus; }
        set
        {
            _lapCounterPingStatus = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(LapCounterPingStatusPropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Right now, no overlay image at all is displayed. What could be wrong?**

---

**UPDATE**

Trace window of my IDE is showing `System.ArgumentException` and `System.FormatException`. 
Could the problem source be a unknown type of enumeration `PingStatus` im the XAML?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10250925/590790 Although this guy got it working already.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

You need 2 things to get this working:

1 - Add an `xmlns` reference in the root element of your XAML file, to the namespace where your Enum is defined:

```
<UserControl ...
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:YourEnumNamespace;assembly=YourAssembly">
```

2 - in the `Value` property of the `DataTrigger`, use the `{x:Static}` form:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LapCounterPingStatus}" Value="{x:Static my:PingStatus.PING_UNKNOWN}">
```

Notice that the Enum type must be prefixed with the xmlns prefix you defined above.

**Edit:**

If your Enum is declared inside a class you need to use the syntax:

`{x:Static namespace:ClassName+EnumName.EnumValue}`

for example:

`{x:Static my:ConfigurationViewModel+PingStatus.PING_UNKNOWN}`

Comment: I added the `xmlns` like this: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Testbench"` and the trigger like that `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LapCounterPingStatus}" Value="{x:Static local:PingStatus.PING_UNKNOWN}">`. No I get the error `Cannot find the type 'PingStatus'`.

Comment: `enum PingStatus` is defined inside the class `MyCompany.TestBench.ConfigurationViewModel`. Do I have to add the class name somewhere?

Comment: It works with your solution _if_ I move the `enum PingStatus` out of class scope. Why?

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find the syntax for a nested type anywhere. Where is the "+" syntax documented? I can't find it in MSDN or in the WPF books I have. I thought it should be in [x:Static Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) but it's not.

Comment: @skst
The + symbol differentiates the containing type from a nested namespace.
`Type t = typeof (System.Environment.SpecialFolder);
Console.WriteLine (t.FullName); // prints  System.Environment+SpecialFolder`

Comment: @skst http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443244/c-sharp-having-a-in-the-class-name

Comment: I think this answer needs to be updated. This solution did not work for me anymore but just using the enum value as string works. Have they changed it at some point? I'm using Xamarin.Forms version 3.3.0.912540

Comment: @hamalaiv AFAIK, xaml in wpf is different than xaml in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: why this breaks designer?

Answer (score 7):

Complete worked example for WPF + MVVM.

Tested on MSVC 2017.

In the view:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some text to be colored by an enum">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusIcon}" Value="{x:Static my:StatusIcon.Warning}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusIcon}" Value="{x:Static my:StatusIcon.Error}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

If using ReSharper, and if the DataContext is set up properly, there will be intellisense when you hit the `.` after `StatusIcon`, i.e. it will show the properties of the enum which are `Debug`, `Info`, `Warning` or `Error`.

If using ReSharper, it will suggest the following update to the namespace in the header for the XAML file(its 
good like that):

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Class.Path.MyViewModel;assembly=MyAssembly"
```

And the VieModel:

```
public enum StatusIcon
{
    Debug,
    Info,
    Warning,
    Error
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public StatusIcon StatusIcon { get; }
}
```

We also use `Fody` for automated binding.

Comment: Are you referring to Fody's PropertyChanged project?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set enum value as DataTrigger Value... Tested on MSVC 2017.

```
<TextBlock Text="Some text to be colored by an enum">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusIcon}" Value="Warning">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusIcon}" Value="Error">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```