# How to set DataGrid's row Background, based on a property value using data bindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

In my XAML code, I want to set the `Background` color of each row, based on a value of the object in one specific row. I have an `ObservableCollection` of `z`, and each of the `z` has a property called `State`. I started out with something like this in my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" 
                Value="{Binding z.StateId, Converter={StaticResource StateIdToColorConverter}}"/>
     </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

This is a wrong approach because x is not a property in my ViewModel class.

In my ViewModel class I have an `ObservableCollection<z>` which is the `ItemsSource` of this `DataGrid`, and a `SelectedItem` of type `z`.

I could bind the color to `SelectedItem`, but this will only change one row in the `DataGrid`.

How can I, based on one property change this rows backgroundcolor?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Use a `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow"> 
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="State1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="State2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I only get: BindingExpression path error: `'State' property not found on 'object' ''z' (HashCode=7162954)'. BindingExpression:Path=State; DataItem='z' (HashCode=7162954); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')` Howcome that it does not find the Property State when my entity holds this, and my database shows the State as a column?

Comment: I hope you are not doing it as `z.State`.

Comment: Just came across this again after time off from wpf, wish i could upvote again!

Comment: This is great. In the solution where I used it, I needed the state to change based on an `enum` value. [This answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917033/datatrigger-on-enum-to-change-image) helped me with that.

Comment: Don't forget the property you bind to has to be `public`

Comment: This is sweet, I had a hard time using Visual selection and then found this way of using XAML to format based on data. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

The same can be done without `DataTrigger` too:

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
         <Setter Property="Background" >
             <Setter.Value>
                 <Binding Path="State" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToBrushConverter}">
                     <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                         <x:Array Type="SolidColorBrush">
                             <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource RedColor}"/>
                             <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource TransparentColor}"/>
                         </x:Array>
                     </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                 </Binding>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Where `BooleanToBrushConverter` is the following class:

```cs
public class BooleanToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Brushes.Transparent;

        Brush[] brushes = parameter as Brush[];
        if (brushes == null)
            return Brushes.Transparent;

        bool isTrue;
        bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out isTrue);

        if (isTrue)
        {
            var brush =  (SolidColorBrush)brushes[0];
            return brush ?? Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        else
        {
            var brush = (SolidColorBrush)brushes[1];
            return brush ?? Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better is the application of a IMultiValueConverter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter) to simply bind more than one property and have the converter return the correct color for the state of those multiple properties (I ommit the sample since its realy similar to the normal converter case but I can post it should anyone need it)

Comment: I use multivalue converter in that cases. One reason because I didn't know how to define an array as parameter of a converter, but also because if there is a multivalue converter, i guess it is for some reason. But why it is better a multivalue converter instead of this solution?

Answer (score 15):

In XAML, add and define a *RowStyle Property for the DataGrid* with a goal to set the *Background of the Row*, to the *Color defined in my Employee Object.*

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="EmployeeList">
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ColorSet}"/>
        </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

And in my Employee Class

```
public class Employee {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string ColorSet { get; set; }

    public Employee() { }

    public Employee(int id, string name, int age)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        if (Age > 50)
        {
            ColorSet = "Green";
        }
        else if (Age > 100)
        {
            ColorSet = "Red";
        }
        else
        {
            ColorSet = "White";
        }
    }
}
```

This way every *Row of the DataGrid* has the *BackGround Color* of the `ColorSet` *Property of my Object*.

Comment: I like this method for the color of the object is centralized in the model itself instead of the view.

Comment: Except that this violates MVVM.  If you don't care, have at it.  But the user experience should not be determined by the model.  That's the View/View Model's job

Comment: I think using lots  of data, will eat lots of RAMs

Comment: How do you set the data of type Employee to the Rows?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
XAML

```xml
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Background" >
      <Setter.Value>
        <Binding Path="State" Converter="{StaticResource BoolToSolidColorBrushConverter}">
          <Binding.ConverterParameter>
            <x:Array Type="SolidColorBrush">
              <SolidColorBrush Color="Salmon"/>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
            </x:Array>
          </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

c# (BoolToSolidColorBrushConverter)

```c#
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  SolidColorBrush[] solidColorBrushes;

  if (parameter is SolidColorBrush[] && ((SolidColorBrush[])parameter).Length > 1)
  {
    solidColorBrushes = (SolidColorBrush[])parameter;
  }
  else
  {
    solidColorBrushes = new SolidColorBrush[] { new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) };
  }

  return (null == value || false == (bool)value) ? solidColorBrushes[1] : solidColorBrushes[0];
}
```