# Styling a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How do I go about styling each row of a datagrid depending on values set in the columns once I have set databinding?  Would I style it using code behind or using XAML Style Triggers?

The problem I have is, it will be dependent on the value set in column[0].

Say column[0] value is either 1,2,3.  I would like to style the row of the datagrid depending on this value.

example

```
    c#
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = schDT.DefaultView

    xaml
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ITEMNUMBER}" Header="ITEMNUMBER" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CODE}" Header="CODE" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DESC}" Header="STD DESCRIPTION" />
```

Thanks for your help as always

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053281/how-to-set-datagrids-row-background-based-on-a-property-value-using-data-bindi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite nasty problem, which I had to solve some time ago.
I used the following code:

Basically: You need a Valueconverter o get the Value of the row / cell simulatneously.
In the example here I used a Multivalueconverter because I needed information about the Colzumn, too - depending on your scenerio, a normal Value-Converter would be enough.

XAML
//for the convers

```
<DataGrid x:Name="bla">
    // use this column if you want to style the header too
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
               AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
               Converter={StaticResource ExcelRowColorConverter}}">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,1,1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF000000"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="DataGrid.Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ExcelDataGridCellColorConverter}" >
                        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
```

// this is the critical piece to style a particular cell

the C#-Code

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="ExcelDataGridCellColorConverter.cs" company="best Research">
//     Copyright (c) best Research. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace myTool.Utils
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Media;

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to convert a cell to its final color. It determines this based on both row and column.
    /// </summary>
   public class ExcelDataGridCellColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to convert a cell to its final color. It determines this based on both row and column.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="values">the parameter array</param>
        /// <param name="targetType">The target type.</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">the parameter.</param>
        /// <param name="culture">the culture.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A Brush
        /// </returns>
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values[1] is DataRow)
            {
                var cell = (DataGridCell)values[0];
                var row = (DataRow)values[1];
                var columnName = cell.Column.SortMemberPath;
                var table = row.Table;

                // this is used because there is a bug in WPF which causes a removed  datarow to be "seen". This happens when deleting empty rows. The Key "lock" should be added by the deleting method and then removed afterwards.
                if (table.ExtendedProperties.Contains("lock"))
                {
                    return Brushes.Gainsboro;
                }

                var colValue = table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1][columnName];
                var rowValue = row[Properties.Resources.ColorColumnName];
                var colorColValue = (Enums.RowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enums.RowState), colValue.ToString(), true);
                var colorRowValue = (Enums.RowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enums.RowState), rowValue.ToString(), true);

                if (colorColValue == Enums.RowState.IsIncluded && colorRowValue == Enums.RowState.IsIncluded)
                {
                    return Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                else if (colorRowValue == Enums.RowState.HeaderRow)
                {
                    return Brushes.Gainsboro;
                }
                else
                { 
                    return Brushes.LightSalmon;
                }
            }

            return Brushes.Blue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Not used
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">the parameter</param>
        /// <param name="targetTypes">The target types.</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">the parameter.</param>
        /// <param name="culture">the culture.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A Brush
        /// </returns>
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, that is another option for me, I found the answer I was looking for (see above).  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, sorry must look harder before posting a question.

[How to set DataGrid's row Background, based on a property value using data bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053281/how-to-set-datagrids-row-background-based-on-a-property-value-using-data-bindi)

Comment: Please close the question then. Duplicates are not [particulary welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) here.