# Row color based on changing ID from MySQL database

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn

I'm trying to change the color of my datagridrows based on the ID change.
I have already bind the data to the datagridview.

I think the easiest way would be to check if the ID in Column 1 is odd or even:

even rowbackground = white
odd rowbackground = brown

The Idea is to get a better overview and collect the items a bit due to background color.

Im complety new to WPF:
At the moment i have just the datagrid included as follows:

`<DataGrid x:Name="cusDetailGrid"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>`

This will be populated by a selectionstring to MySqlDB.

Any Ideas how to get this working?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Set [AlternatingRowBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.alternatingrowbackground?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: I have tried already but this is not what im looking for or i dont know how to use it how i want. Let's say my table looks like this:

1 XY (white)
1 XY (white)
1 XY (white)
2 ZB (brown)
2 ZB (brown)
3 Bla (white)
3 Bla (white)
3 Bla (white

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053281/how-to-set-datagrids-row-background-based-on-a-property-value-using-data-bindi) looks like a good answer.

One other way you might be able to achieve this is something along the lines of creating a LoadingRow event; you could try something like this and then just adjust to wherever the ID column is located:

```
private void Dg_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataContext)).Row.ItemArray[0]) % 2 != 0)
                {
                    e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```