# C# WPF DataGrid change row format (e.g. background) on value PropertyChange

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My goal is to change the row / cell style of a DataGrid, when the underlying value property changed. It is indepented of the value, the DataGrid should only show that it has changed. I have a list of Tournament.cs objects which fires property change events. I added a method which listens to these changes in the MainWindow.cs and should find that object in the DataGrid and change the format of the related row / cell. Unfortunally it doesn't work for me. The method is called and I am able to find the `DataGridRow` object of the Tournament, but changing the format of it e.g. the background has no effect. How can I make this work? Find snippets of my code below.

This is the DataGrid. Each row represents a tournament object and each cell a property, which can be updated externally. Goal is to highlight the updated value.

[image]

**UPDATE**

While creating a minimal example I found, that the problem is the automatic sorting which immediately removes the formatting again.
I guess there is no way around having a map etc. to save the updated state and binding somehow. In the example app below you can trigger that behaviour by sorting a column.

MainWindow.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using TurnierChecker.Basic;
using WPFTestProject.Model;

namespace WPFTestProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initial loading of data.
            this.TournamentList = new SortableBindingList<Tournament>();
            this.TournamentList.ListChanged += this.TournamentListChanged;

            // tie View with ViewModel
            this.TournamentGrid.DataContext = this.TournamentList;
        }

        public SortableBindingList<Tournament> TournamentList { get; private set; }



        /// <summary>
        /// Property change method. Should add a animation / format to the related cell to highlight the change.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="ListChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void TournamentListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Property of tournament change.
            if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
            {
                Tournament tmnt = (sender as SortableBindingList<Tournament>)?.ElementAt(e.NewIndex);

                DataGridRow row = this.TournamentGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(tmnt) as DataGridRow;

                switch (e.PropertyDescriptor?.Name)
                {
                    case nameof(Tournament.Date):
                        if (row != null)
                        {
                            DataGridCell cell = this.GetCell(this.TournamentGrid, row, 0);

                            if (cell != null)
                            {
                                cell.Background = Brushes.Orange;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case nameof(Tournament.Series):
                        if (row != null)
                        {
                            DataGridCell cell = this.GetCell(this.TournamentGrid, row, 1);

                            if (cell != null)
                            {
                                cell.Background = Brushes.Orange;

                            }
                        }

                        break;

                    // Default property change.
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the visual child.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="parent">The parent.</param>
        /// <returns>The child.</returns>
        private T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent)
            where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = this.GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }

                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return child;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the cell.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="grid">The grid.</param>
        /// <param name="row">The row.</param>
        /// <param name="column">The column.</param>
        /// <returns>The cell.</returns>
        private DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
        {
            if (row != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = this.GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

                if (presenter == null)
                {
                    grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
                    presenter = this.GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
                }

                DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter?.ItemContainerGenerator?.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                return cell;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the AddTournamentButton control. Adds a tournament.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void AddTournamentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Tournament tmnt = new Tournament();
            tmnt.Date = DateTime.Now;
            tmnt.Series = "Sample Changing Series Name Nr. " + new Random().Next(1, 10);
            this.TournamentList.Add(tmnt);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the ChangeButton control. Changes a random tournament data. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void ChangeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            int cnt = this.TournamentList.Count();

            if (cnt < 1) { return; }


            switch (new Random().Next(0,2))
            {
                case 0:
                    this.TournamentList[new Random().Next(0, cnt - 1)].Date = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.TournamentList[new Random().Next(0, cnt - 1)].Series = "Sample Changing Series Name Nr. " + new Random().Next(1, 10);
                    break;
            }
           

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the ApplyButton control. Should remove the updated highlight of a cell.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // How can I remove the applied format / animation from the DataGrid-Cells.
            var rows = GetDataGridRows(this.TournamentGrid);

            foreach (DataGridRow row in rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.TournamentGrid.Columns.Count;i++)
                {
                    DataGridCell cell = this.GetCell(this.TournamentGrid, row, i);
                    cell.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                }

            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
        {
            var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
            if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
            foreach (var item in itemsSource)
            {
                var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                if (null != row) yield return row;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="WPFTestProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="AddTournamentButton" Grid.Row="0" Content="Add" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" Click="AddTournamentButton_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="ChangeButton" Grid.Row="0" Content="Change" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" Click="ChangeButton_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="ApplyButton" Grid.Row="0" Content="Apply" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" Click="ApplyButton_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        
        <DataGrid x:Name="TournamentGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" AlternationCount="2" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" RowHeight="28" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--Tournament Date-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=\{0: ddd dd.MM.yy HH:mm U\\hr\}, ConverterCulture=de-DE}" Header="Datum" Width="160" MinWidth="170" SortDirection="Ascending"/>
                <!--Tournament Series-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Series}" Header="Serie"  Width="410" MinWidth="395"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

Model: Tournament.cs

```cs
namespace WPFTestProject.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    /// <summary>
    /// The tournament model.
    /// </summary>
    public class Tournament : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The date and time of the tournament.
        /// </summary>
        private DateTime? date;

        /// <summary>
        /// The series  of the tournament.
        /// </summary>
        private string series;


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Tournament"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public Tournament()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tritt ein, wenn sich ein Eigenschaftswert ändert.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date and time of the tournament.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The date and time.
        /// </value>
        public DateTime? Date
        {
            get => this.date;
            set => this.SetField(ref this.date, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the series of the tournament.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The series.
        /// </value>
        public string Series
        {
            get => this.series;
            set => this.SetField(ref this.series, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when [property changed].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the field.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The property type.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="field">The field.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns true if the property was changed.</returns>
        private bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                return false;
            }

            field = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Basic: SortableBindingList.cs

```cs
namespace WPFTestProject.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    /// <summary>
    ///  Sortable binding list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The innertype.</typeparam>
    /// <seealso cref="System.ComponentModel.BindingList&lt;T&gt;" />
    public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, PropertyComparer<T>> comparers;
        private bool isSorted;
        private ListSortDirection listSortDirection;
        private PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SortableBindingList{T}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public SortableBindingList()
            : base(new List<T>())
        {
            this.comparers = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyComparer<T>>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SortableBindingList{T}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="enumeration">The enumeration.</param>
        public SortableBindingList(IEnumerable<T> enumeration)
            : base(new List<T>(enumeration))
        {
            this.comparers = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyComparer<T>>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the list supports sorting.
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the list is sorted.
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool IsSortedCore
        {
            get { return this.isSorted; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the property descriptor that is used for sorting the list if sorting is implemented in a derived class; otherwise, returns <see langword="null" />.
        /// </summary>
        protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
        {
            get { return this.propertyDescriptor; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the direction the list is sorted.
        /// </summary>
        protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
        {
            get { return this.listSortDirection; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the list supports searching.
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool SupportsSearchingCore
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies the sort core.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property">The property.</param>
        /// <param name="direction">The direction.</param>
        protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            var itemsList = (List<T>)this.Items;
            if (this.comparers == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            if (!this.comparers.TryGetValue(propertyType, out PropertyComparer<T> comparer))
            {
                comparer = new PropertyComparer<T>(property, direction);
                this.comparers.Add(propertyType, comparer);
            }

            comparer.SetPropertyAndDirection(property, direction);
            itemsList.Sort(comparer);

            this.propertyDescriptor = property;
            this.listSortDirection = direction;
            this.isSorted = true;

            this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes any sort applied with <see cref="M:System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.ApplySortCore(System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor,System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection)" />
        /// if sorting is implemented in a derived class; otherwise, raises <see cref="T:System.NotSupportedException" />.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void RemoveSortCore()
        {
            this.isSorted = false;
            this.propertyDescriptor = base.SortPropertyCore;
            this.listSortDirection = base.SortDirectionCore;

            this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the core.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property">The property.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <returns>The core value.</returns>
        protected override int FindCore(PropertyDescriptor property, object key)
        {
            int count = this.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                T element = this[i];
                if (property?.GetValue(element)?.Equals(key) ?? false)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Basic: PropertyComparer.cs

```cs
namespace WPFTestProject.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Reflection;

    /// <summary>
    /// Property comparer class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type.</typeparam>
    /// <seealso cref="System.Collections.Generic.IComparer&lt;T&gt;" />
    public class PropertyComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly IComparer comparer;
        private PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor;
        private int reverse;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PropertyComparer{T}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property">The property.</param>
        /// <param name="direction">The direction.</param>
        public PropertyComparer(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            this.propertyDescriptor = property;
            Type comparerForPropertyType = typeof(Comparer<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType);
            this.comparer = comparerForPropertyType.InvokeMember("Default", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public, null, null, null) as IComparer;
            this.SetListSortDirection(direction);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares two objects and returns a value indicating whether one is less than, equal to, or greater than the other.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The first object to compare.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The second object to compare.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A signed integer that indicates the relative values of <paramref name="x" /> and <paramref name="y" />, as shown in the following table.
        /// <list type="table"><listheader><term> Value</term><description> Meaning</description></listheader><item><term> Less than zero</term><description><paramref name="x" /> is less than <paramref name="y" />.</description></item><item><term> Zero</term><description><paramref name="x" /> equals <paramref name="y" />.</description></item><item><term> Greater than zero</term><description><paramref name="x" /> is greater than <paramref name="y" />.</description></item></list>
        /// </returns>
        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            if (this.comparer == null)
            {
                return this.reverse;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.reverse * this.comparer.Compare(this.propertyDescriptor.GetValue(x), this.propertyDescriptor.GetValue(y));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the property and direction.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="descriptor">The descriptor.</param>
        /// <param name="direction">The direction.</param>
        public void SetPropertyAndDirection(PropertyDescriptor descriptor, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            this.SetPropertyDescriptor(descriptor);
            this.SetListSortDirection(direction);
        }

        private void SetPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            this.propertyDescriptor = descriptor;
        }

        private void SetListSortDirection(ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            this.reverse = direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053281/how-to-set-datagrids-row-background-based-on-a-property-value-using-data-bindi

Comment: The examples mentioned are depending on a specific value of the underyling object. But I don't have such. Isn't there a other solution beside introducing something like a "hasChanged" boolean parameter for each parameter of the model that is viewed in the DataGrid?

Comment: If so, you can use Converter to convert specific value to true and the others to false. It is just a matter of the place of such logic.

Comment: Again .... the model is just a snippet. It has a lot of properties. To use a converter I would have to introduce an additional flag for each property, that indicates that a property has changed its value. This seems impractical to me. Isn't there a solution to set format in the ProperChangeEvent-Method?

Comment: You don't need to change your Tournament's properties. The Converters are for binding. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data

Comment: Ty for your help, but please give an example. The linked stuff are the basics I am already aware off, but maybe I am missing something. How would it possible to set a blinking animation for the row or cell, if the Date of the tournament is changed externally. I added a picture of my DataGrid in the description. Some columns already have converters active.

Comment: @Blakhar: Could you please provide a minimal compilable example of your issue?

Comment: You can create a map where you store the item as key and a data object (e.g. PropertyInfo) as value. The PropertyInfo could itself expose a map that has the property's name as key and a bool as value. The boolean value indicates that the value of the property was changed since the last map read. Then bind to the <item, PropertyInfo> map using a converter that extracts the boolean value based on the current item/cell by calling e.g. GetHasPropertyValueChanged(propertyName).

Comment: This method then clears the property changed flag for the queried property. You would have to use a MultiBinding for this task and pass in the row item (DataContext), the source that defines the map and a boolean value on this source that flags a property change for the complete map. The last requires another dedicated boolean property e.g. HasTableDataChanged, which has the purpose to trigger the MultiBinding. This way you don't have to modify the data model to add a dedicated property (although this would be the simplest solution).

Comment: Updated the problem description. The sorting removes the formatting again. I will try your solution later @BionicCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on BionicCodes answer: I added a HashSet to my `Tournament` object which holds the namens of the changed properties. Below is my solution:

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="WPFTestProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:WPFTestProject.Converter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:PropertiesUpdatesSetToBoolConverter x:Key="PropertiesUpdatesSetToBoolConverter" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PropertiesUpdatesSetToBoolConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Column.Binding.Path.Path" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            <Binding Path="PropertiesUpdatedSet" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions >
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="BlinkingAnimation">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:03" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridCell.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Red" To="Black" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BlinkingAnimation"/>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="AddTournamentButton" Grid.Row="0" Content="Add" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" Click="AddTournamentButton_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="ChangeButton" Grid.Row="0" Content="Change" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" Click="ChangeButton_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="ApplyButton" Grid.Row="0" Content="Apply" Width="100" Margin="10,10,10,10" Click="ApplyButton_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        
        <DataGrid x:Name="TournamentGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" AlternationCount="2" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" RowHeight="28" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--Tournament Date-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=\{0: ddd dd.MM.yy HH:mm U\\hr\}, ConverterCulture=de-DE}" Header="Datum" Width="160" MinWidth="170" SortDirection="Ascending"/>
                <!--Tournament Series-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Series}" Header="Serie"  Width="410" MinWidth="395" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using WPFTestProject.Model;

namespace WPFTestProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();


            // Initial loading of data.
            this.TournamentList = new SortableBindingList<Tournament>();

            // tie View with ViewModel
            this.TournamentGrid.DataContext = this.TournamentList;
        }

        public SortableBindingList<Tournament> TournamentList { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the AddTournamentButton control. Adds a tournament.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void AddTournamentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Tournament tmnt = new Tournament();
            tmnt.Date = DateTime.Now;
            tmnt.Series = "Sample Changing Series Name Nr. " + new Random().Next(1, 10);
            this.TournamentList.Add(tmnt);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the ChangeButton control. Changes a random tournament data. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void ChangeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            int cnt = this.TournamentList.Count();

            if (cnt < 1) { return; }


            switch (new Random().Next(0,2))
            {
                case 0:
                    this.TournamentList[new Random().Next(0, cnt - 1)].Date = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.TournamentList[new Random().Next(0, cnt - 1)].Series = "Sample Changing Series Name Nr. " + new Random().Next(1, 10);
                    break;
            }
           

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Click event of the ApplyButton control. Should remove the updated highlight of a cell.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          foreach (Tournament tmnt in this.TournamentList)
            {
                tmnt.PropertiesUpdatedSet.Clear();
                tmnt.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tournament.PropertiesUpdatedSet));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model: Tournament.cs

```cs
namespace WPFTestProject.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    /// <summary>
    /// The tournament model.
    /// </summary>
    public class Tournament : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The date and time of the tournament.
        /// </summary>
        private DateTime? date;

        /// <summary>
        /// The series  of the tournament.
        /// </summary>
        private string series;


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Tournament"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public Tournament()
        {
            PropertiesUpdatedSet = new HashSet<string>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tritt ein, wenn sich ein Eigenschaftswert ändert.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date and time of the tournament.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The date and time.
        /// </value>
        public DateTime? Date
        {
            get => this.date;
            set => this.SetField(ref this.date, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the series of the tournament.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The series.
        /// </value>
        public string Series
        {
            get => this.series;
            set => this.SetField(ref this.series, value);
        }

        public HashSet<string> PropertiesUpdatedSet {  get; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Called when [property changed].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the field.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The property type.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="field">The field.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns true if the property was changed.</returns>
        private bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                return false;
            }

            field = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (!PropertiesUpdatedSet.Contains(propertyName))
            {
                PropertiesUpdatedSet.Add(propertyName);
                this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PropertiesUpdatedSet));
            }


            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Converter: PropertiesUpdatesSetToBoolConverter.cs

```cs
namespace WPFTestProject.Converter
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a string value to visibility property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="IMultiValueConverter" />
    public class PropertiesUpdatesSetToBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a string value to visibility property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value produced by the binding source.</param>
        /// <param name="targetType">The type of the binding target property.</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
        /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A converted value. If the method returns <see langword="null" />, the valid null value is used.
        /// </returns>
        public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value[1] is HashSet<string> flags))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value[0]?.ToString())) {
                return false;
            }

            bool result = flags.Contains(value[0].ToString());
            return flags.Contains(value[0].ToString());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value that is produced by the binding target.</param>
        /// <param name="targetType">The type to convert to.</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
        /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A converted value. If the method returns <see langword="null" />, the valid null value is used.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="NotImplementedException">Not implemented</exception>
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have something for you. Its a bit out there, and isn't contained in XAML, but I'll try nonetheless.

This is a snippet from my Datagrid rows:

```html
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Id" Header="EmployeeId" Binding="{Binding EmployeeId}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="HasLeased" Header="HasLeasedCar" Binding="{Binding HasLeasedCar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RFID" Header="RFID" Binding="{Binding Rfid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RFIDMapped" Header="RFIDMapped" Binding="{Binding RfidMapped, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Created" Header="CreatedDate" Binding="{Binding CreatedDate}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Modified" Header="ModifiedDate" Binding="{Binding ModifiedDate}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Now my `Employee` object has a `HasNew` attribute for every editable property.

So for example I have `RFID` and `HasNewRFID`, in this case it's also important that the column headers have the same name as those `HasNew` attributes.

```
private bool _nameInit;
private string _oldName = null!;
private string _name = null!;

public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set
    {
        if (!_nameInit)
        {
            _oldName = value;
            _name = value;
            _nameInit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (value.Trim() == _name && value.Trim() != _oldName)
            {
                return;
            }

            _name = value.Trim();
            OnPropertyChanged();
            HasNewName = _name != _oldName;
        }
    }
}

private bool _hasNewName;

public bool HasNewName
{
    get => _hasNewName;
    set
    {
        _hasNewName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public bool HasNew => HasNewName || HasNewRFID || etc
```

Now my main idea was, that I could have written a style for every instance but I wanted to automate.

```
#region Style Support
public void CreateSources()
{
    ILog log = _logger.Log().Start();

    try
    {
        DataGridColumn[] editableColumns = DatGrdEmployee.Columns.Where(c => !c.IsReadOnly).ToArray();

        string[] na = editableColumns.Select(c => "HasNew" + (c.Header as string)).ToArray();

        Dictionary<string, Style> styles = CreateSource(na);

        foreach (DataGridColumn c in editableColumns)
        {
            var style = styles.Where(s => s.Key == (c.Header as string)).ToArray()[0].Value;

            c.CellStyle = style;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex);
    }

    log.End();
}

public Dictionary<string, Style> CreateSource(string[] pathNames)
{
    // ReSharper disable once CoVariantArrayConversion
    ILog log = _logger.Log().Start(pathNames);

    Dictionary<string, Style> styles = new();

    try
    {
        Setter orangeBackground = new(BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange));
        Setter transparentBackground = new(BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent));

        foreach (string pathName in pathNames)
        {
            Style style = new();
            style.Setters.Add(transparentBackground);

            DataTrigger dataTrigger = new()
            {
                Binding = new Binding
                {
                    Path = ((PropertyPath)(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PropertyPath)).ConvertFromInvariantString(pathName))!)
                },
                Value = true,
                Setters = { orangeBackground }
            };

            style.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);
            string newPathName = pathName.Replace("HasNew", "");

            styles.Add(newPathName, style);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex);
    }

    return log.End(styles);
}

#endregion
```

So if we go step by step: at the very beginning I simply collect all the columns which are interesting for me/should react to value changes.

Then in na I combine all the headers with `HasNew` so that I have a array filled with `HasNewName`, `HasNewRFID` and so on.

Then in `CreateSource()`, I create a dictionary that holds strings and styles. The end goal will be to have it filled with the header name and style.

Then we create two setters one for the changed value and one for normal status.

The we go into the `foreach` loop which starts by creating a style and adding or normal setter.

Then we create a DataTrigger which will create a binding, it looks complicated but at the end this

```
Binding = new Binding
{
    Path = ((PropertyPath)(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PropertyPath)).ConvertFromInvariantString(pathName))!)
}
```

Only really means `Binding ="{Binding Path= HasNew[Property]}"`

The full `DataTrigger` code translates to

```html
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasNewName}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
    </DataTrigger>
```

We then add that trigger to the style. Afterwards we remove the `HasNew` from the string so we get our header back and then we add that header name and style to our dictionary. Now rinse and repeat and you get the idea.

Right now a style would look something like this

```html
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasNewName}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

To briefly explain a DataTrigger inside a Style. It basically just means when X condition is fullfilled set Y Property to value Z and if it isn't fullfilled value Y will be its default.

Once we have all the styles we return the Dictionary and the iterate through our columns. We get the style out of the dict where the header has the appropriate name and the we set the columns cell style to that style leading to every cell in that column now having that style. Now don't worry every cell is still bound to the employee of its row. And that's it. Now if you really want to not have the c# code you must do each of the styles individually for every column.

But now lets say you want something more simple that's just checks: has there been a Change and the Recolor the full row.

Now that's fairly easy

```html
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasNew}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Just add this directly below your DataGridColumns (not under each Col but under the Section in which the cols are defined) and done.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9YO6.png) it what a cell change looks like to me. I censored a lot of rows because the other entries are actual people and I'm not going dox company data

Comment: If you found this helpfull a Upvote or a Correct Marker would be greatly appreciated^^