# data trigger with enum

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics

I have an Enum:

```
namespace LibiqCommonStructures
{
    using System;

    public enum ItemStatusType
    {
        NotImplemented,
        New,
        Processed,
        Missing,
        NotUsed,
        Failed
    }
}


<igWPF:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Path=Images}" ActiveDataItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"  MaxHeight="300">
                <igWPF:XamDataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:DataRecordCellArea}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type igWPF:DataRecordCellArea}}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Record.DataItem.ItemStatus}" Value="{x:Static libIq:ItemStatusType.Missing}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tomato"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </igWPF:XamDataGrid.Resources>
                <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                    <igWPF:FieldLayoutSettings SelectionTypeRecord="Single" AutoGenerateFields="False" AllowDelete="False"/>
                </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings >
                    <igWPF:FieldSettings Width="Auto" AllowEdit="False" />
                </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
                <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
```

I want to change the background color of the row when the enum is ItemStatusType.Missing

i can see missing the in the binding but the color of the row doesn't change.
maybe something is wrong with my **x:static**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the enum string in the Value. It will work:

```
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Record.DataItem.ItemStatus}" Value="Missing">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tomato"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: are yo raising PropertyChanged on ItemStatus?

Comment: yes i am, as far as i can see this is not the way to use enum in datatrigger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917033/datatrigger-on-enum-to-change-image

Comment: sometimes it works sometimes not, might be virtualiztion problem?